# What is the meaning of "as" in "as we see"?

Tags: word-meaning

How to understand the grammar of "As we see in this section, xxxxxxx"? "we see in this section" is not a full sentence so "as" is followed by an adverbial phrase? What is the meaning of "as" here?

Comment: "in the way that; like:" (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: "As we see in this section" is not a full sentence either. Presumably your 'xxxxxx' goes on to summarise what will be shown in the current section.

Comment: Have you tried a bilingual dictionary for your language?

Comment: It means "In the way that we see" or "Like we see".  **As** and **like** are often interchangeable in English.  It's very similar in usage to words such as *como* in Spanish, *come*  in Italian, or *comme* in French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by Kate Bunting  correctly indicates, "*"As we see in this section" is not a full sentence*". Moreover, the previous sentence in this answer is an example of this construction. The word 'As" in such sentences indicates that one thing is an example or illustration o0f the other.  Several examples (of my own construction) are:

> - As Charles should have known, the King's power is only absolute when enough of the subjects tolerate it.
> - As Godel's theorem demonstrates, a formal system cannot be both comprehensive and consistent.
> - As *The Lord of the Rings* shows, epic fantasy based on mythological ideas could be popular in the twentieth century.
> - As Whimsy said in *Gaudy Night*, the detective story is the most moral form of fiction.
> - As we will demonstrate in this chapter, magnetic fields are merely the relativistic transforms of the fields of fast-moving electric charges, so no magnetic charges are needed.
> - As *Animal Farm* shows, allegory can be a very effective way of telling a story.

The word "as" provides the connection between the two phrases (usually clauses).